# Nonparametric Outlier Detection

Tags: machine-learning, data-mining, anomaly-detection, outlier, non-parametric

Which Nonparametric outlier detection do you suggest to detect outliers (red points) in these plots? I have tested std, IQR, etc., but no good result. It is just one vector including normal and outliers. Thanks for your help.
[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you please explain the axis? How many vectors does the upper plot contain? Four vectors, each starting from 80, 30, -30, -40 or only single vector?

Comment: This is just one vector.

Comment: Can you plot this such that the temporal structure of the data is clear? Right now points along time are overlapping

Comment: Without better info (requested above) it is not really possible to answer this